# Tridion API source for a beginner

Tags: api

I would like to know which can be given as a good source for a beginner to learn Tridion API methods and functions. Is there any such consolidated documentation on the sdltridionworld?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a number of APIs available for SDL Tridion. Here's an overview:

**TOM.NET** - The CMS templating API, written in .NET, runs on the CM machine

**Core Service** - A .Net web service API, allows you to interact with items in the CMS from another machine than the CMS server itself.

**Content Delivery** - This is a front end API allowing you to work with published CMS content, for example in a news page, get all 'published news' - this is .NET and Java

**Anguilla** - This is a JavaScript API that let's you extend the CMS' user interface

There are a number of other items too such as CMS Event System, Custom Resolvers, Custom Deployers, but the above I consider to be the main APIs.

So if you know for example, 'I'd like to build some website templates' your best place to start would be the TOM.NET API.

SDL does run developer [training courses](http://www.sdl.com/services/education-certification/training-overview/). I'd recommend you sign yourself up to one of these, as there's certainly a lot to get through and the introduction and developer courses cover them very well.

Comment: Yeah I agree with John here, there is a Getting Started guide in the 2013 SP1 documentation, but that doesn't cover API's (yet), and there is no SDL Tridion for Dummies written yet. The [developer training tracks](http://www.sdl.com/services/education-certification/training-product/web-content-management/sdltridion-application-developer.html) are your best bet to get started from scratch.

Answer (score 8):

If you have valid sdl tridion world user id, you can download various resources including CHM files, manuals and whitepapers for various APIs.

Below picture shows the link from where you can download the API documentations once you are logged into the SDL Tridion World

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I always suggest for new Tridion developers to choose a site (news sites work well) and try to build this in Tridion, from the beginning.  This means you will:

- Define the Blueprint
- Create Schemas
- Create Templates with the design of the chosen site
- Use Broker API to get Dynamic content (Java or .Net)
- Optionally, use DD4T + .Net MVC to build the site

Then, you can choose to dig more into the other APIs, such as the Core Service.

I normally plan about 1 week, full time, for the above.

See the link in John's post about the excellent SDL Tridion training courses.  If you're not lucky enough to attend those, then I would find a local Tridion expert on your team and try to create your own site from nothing with their support, help, and code samples.

Comment: That's going to be a very full 1 week :) Hopefully you will have guidance in that process, otherwise you will post a lot of questions here, on TRex :). But at the end of it, you will know a LOT about Tridion. Promise! :)

Comment: I did a couple of workshops, handling the first three bullets in only three days, so adding another two for some basic Broker stuff will work in my opinion. But depending on your audience you might indeed require a bit more time.