# Understanding Core Service API

Tags: 2013

Hi i am New to SDL Tridion please suggest me needed resources and links to understand Core Service API,Now i am having API DOCS which is helpful but take too much time to understand it throughly .if anyone having resource/links which help to get it easily.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start learning SDL Tridion from the SDL Live Content link - http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/ (Require Login) and specific to Core Service you can refer [THIS](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-9E83FE0C-F650-451F-BEB3-7960A4925D90&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-9E83FE0C-F650-451F-BEB3-7960A4925D90.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-9E83FE0C-F650-451F-BEB3-7960A4925D90&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dcore%2520service&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1405334574240&currentQuery=core%2520service&currentScope=) link (Require Login)

Additionally, you can refer this question on this site - [Tridion API source for a beginner](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/tridion-api-source-for-a-beginner/3825#3825)

Further, you may choose from various Training provided by SDL and get hands on knwoledge about various aspects of SDL Tridion along with Core Service.

Answer (score 2):

The Tridion Core Service is a WCF 3.5 service.  In the web.config or app.config you will need the WCF bindings to point to the Tridion Server.  Also, since it is a WCF service, you can run the code locally and connect to a remote Tridion instance, assuming the firewall allows you.  If the firewall blocks the call, you can use the http binding.

Then, you will need a few DLLs and a sample config from Tridion to get started.  See my [blog post here](http://www.curlette.com/?p=1095) for a good example.

Finally, a good understanding of the Data Object model will be a big help, like knowing the difference between ComponentData and IdentifiableObjectData.  My post on [UFOs helps explain that](http://www.curlette.com/?p=362).

I usually start with a simple console app and then use client.Read(URI, new ReadOptions()) and then go from there.